# Problems with venv module when there are multiple versions of python in the path

Tags: python, path

I'm in Windows 10 and  I have python 3.7, 3.8, and 3.9 in the Path

The procedure that I used to install and leave the multiple versions on the path was the following: First I installed `python 3.7` in `C:\Users\MyExampleUser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\`, then I copied the `python.exe` into `python37.exe`. I did exactly the same for the other versions,

This allows me to call a desired python version by adding the `3x` suffix. The default python version is 3.7 (i.e when I call python without suffix). Now,
When I want to create a virtual environment using `venv`, doing

```py
python -m venv .venv
```

It does not cause me any problem (i.e virtualenv with `python 3.7` which is the default), but If I add any suffix (including 3.7)

```py
python3x -m venv .venv
```

I get this error

```py
Error: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the specified file
```

If I add the full path to the python folder, for example,

```
C:\Users\MyExampleUser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe -m venv .venv
```

I have no problems.

I suspect that the `venv` script is calling the executable somewhere as `python.exe`, which goes against the suffix I added to differentiate the multiple versions of python, and I imagine many other modules do the same. My question is how to deal well with multiple versions without incurring these errors.